# Wrap a function whose return value is Promise<T> | undefined to always return Promise and maintain typing

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have a function `callback<T>` whose return value is either `Promise<T>` or `undefined`. Now I want to create a wrapping function that will execute the function and always returns a Promise - in case the callback function returned `undefined`, the Promise should resolve with `undefined`.

The code isn't the problem, but maintaining type inference in Typescript. How would the function signature have to look so that the typing is maintained?

(non-working) example:

```js
function wrap<T>(callback: () => Promise<T> | undefined): Promise<T> | Promise<undefined>

// inferred signature should be Promise<undefined>
const a = wrap(() => undefined)

// inferred signature should be Promise<number>
const b = wrap(() => Promise.resolve(5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is a function overload:

```
function wrap<T>(callback: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T>;
function wrap(callback: () => undefined): Promise<undefined>;
function wrap<T>(callback: () => any): Promise<T | undefined> {
    const result = callback();
    if (typeof result === "undefined") {
        return Promise.resolve(undefined);
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOAeAKgPgAoJ0AbUgI3QgGsAuRQgSkQF59EAFVOAWxgDOAUzz4mDbn0EiCAbgBQoSLAQoMmYmUrV6jFu0TgAJkOAwwQo+K49+w7MdPnL+BUujwkaLKM3kqtAzMbBzoYACe1pJ2MogAPoZgJmYWRhwA3vKI2YgQCAJQiKhCAiCkhay5WgE0zAo5iDDAjFDhmEJwzcWl5WyslQBEjimWAyyZDQ3FUCCoSNHSAHTdcKQAbkKEw85W9TkAvlk507NI3WVQCofyAPQ3jWDAQqjFRogCMADmYOgzxe8ACzgZTeFCENik9m2qXw8jyYAKiHQbDUWEIwQM0MsTHkt3u5ieL0s7y+Pz+4IEQJBiDBEJi2DAIF4YNQsPhiIoKO8GgxHAWwmWJVWG0IAFYmEwgA)

That can also be expressed in a type if that's useful:

```
type Wrapper = {
    <T>(callback: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T>;
    (callback: () => undefined): Promise<undefined>;
}

const wrap: Wrapper = (callback: () => any) {
    const result = callback();
    if (typeof result === "undefined") {
        return Promise.resolve(undefined);
    }
    return result;
};
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gTgQzJOUC8UDeAoKeoA8AKgHwAUAxggDbUBGCFA1gFxRkCU6JUACnAHsAtgEsAzhGIkObfsPGTSAblz5KNeo1bsuaHgFcAdgBMIAMxGGIxmX0GiJBI6YtXjJFQF9s2CgMNiwFAA7ohgbPBIKOjsVLQMzGyc3FAIhiBcOPhQfgFBcBBi+tRBGHGazJwq2SJm7KCQAnUFRSXoaBgARM7mltadmarZeAXA+nCGdvISAHQtAtQAbhBkPa7WHNX43tmj45MtxcBeKtgA9GdQlmYQcAXGUGIiAOaGCGMFjwAWAsUPdNA5A5JGs+u5fP5AqkYqEkGRknooKC3BwfBcroYbndrI8Xm8PtAxD8-lAAVNgQRDPohAC4CQIXlSTCwvDdDwgQo5oUFssyABWDgcIA)